# Handle tap event in presentingViewController to close side menu

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/Yalantis/Side-Menu.iOS/tree/swift_2.0) to present a side menu. I need to dismiss the menu just by tapping anywhere outside the menu.

What I have tried:

1) Handle tap events on the viewController (the responsible of presenting the menu)

**Result:** The tap events fired only when the menu is closed and once the menu is opened no more tap events

2) Handle tap events on the MenuController

**Result:**  receive only tap events of the menu it self

3) Add tap recognizer to ViewController when the menu is presented using `presentingViewController`

Result: didn't receive events

here is the code in `MenuViewController`:

```
private var tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let viewController = self.presentingViewController as? ViewController {
        tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
        viewController.container.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture!)
    } 
}

func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    let location = recognizer.locationInView(view)
    print("menu \(location)")
}
```

I'm really stack. Can't figure out how to receive tap events outside the menu once it's presented.

Note: I'm using the [swift_2.0 Branch](https://github.com/Yalantis/Side-Menu.iOS/tree/swift_2.0)

Edit:

I was able to receive tap events outside the menu by attached the tap recognizer to the key window:

```
        tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleTap:")
          UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture!)
```

But now the menu which is a `UITableViewController` can't respond to the tap events `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

Edit2:

I was able to solve the issue of the block touch events on the TableView with implementing the delegate method of `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` :

```
  func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {

    let location = touch.locationInView(view)
    if !CGRectContainsPoint(self.tableView.frame, location){
        delegate?.menuDidCancel(self)
    }
    return false
}
```

Problem solved but is it the best solution any other elegant one ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue of the block touch events on the TableView with implementing the delegate method of `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and return false after I dismiss the menu if the user tap outside

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {

        let location = touch.locationInView(view)
        if !CGRectContainsPoint(self.tableView.frame, location){
            delegate?.menuDidCancel(self)
        }
        return false
    }
```